# How to define file entry is file or folder in Google Drive SDK v2?

Tags: android, sdk, google-drive-api

I'm going to get list of files/folders on Google Drive (using Android Google Drive SDK V2). I've found https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/list method for this, but i can't see any `isFile()` or `isFolder` property or method for the file. How can i do it? I've found `kind` property but is this what i need?

How can i get full file path for the file on drive?

How can i check the file exists?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at mimeType.  You could have found this easily by looking at the file.list output on the oauth playground since the mimetype contains the word "folder".

Comment: solved about file/folder detection. what about other questions?

Answer (score 1):

"mimeType": "application/vnd.google-apps.folder"

You could also add a q for (Query string)  then you can have it return just the folders for you.  Then for each folder query its contents.  https://developers.google.com/drive/search-parameters

But it depends on what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

1. Compare the item's `mimeType` to `application/vnd.google-apps.folder` - this is the mimeType of a Folder in GDrive.
2. Every item has a `parents` property that holds an array of parent folder. I guess you'll have to *"manually"* browse them and their parents to construct the absolute path of an item. Note that an item might have multiple parent folders.
3. You can either provide a query parameter in your request that will make the server return only existing files (`trashed = false`) or check the file's labels after you have fetched the info for that file. Of course this might vary depending on your meaning of "existing"...

Comment: how can the file have few parents?

Comment: You can see more info for each field of a File object in the File's reference page - https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files. I suppose each parent just has a shortcut for the real file, which is actually located somewhere else but it's a GDrive implementation detail actually.